# android.security.KeyStoreException: Key user not authenticated while using setUserAuthenticationRequired

Tags: android, android-biometric

Using KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder to generate key but it throws exception when `setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)` is set.

```
private Key getKey(String KEY_ALIAS) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
  KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry secretKeyEntry = (KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry) getKeyStore().getEntry(KEY_ALIAS, null);
  if (secretKeyEntry != null) {
    return secretKeyEntry.getSecretKey();
  } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    KeyGenerator generator = KeyGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES, ANDROID_KEY_STORE);
    generator.init(new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(
      KEY_ALIAS,
      KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
      .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_GCM)
      .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_NONE)
      .setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)
      .setInvalidatedByBiometricEnrollment(true)
      .setRandomizedEncryptionRequired(false)
      .build()
    );
    return generator.generateKey();
  } else {
    return getAESKey(KEY_ALIAS);
  }
}
```

The error is:

> 2022-05-04 18:47:47.643
> 23632-23733/com.bmo.enterprise.investorlinemobile E/Capacitor/Plugin:
> Failed to save credentials
> javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException
> at android.security.keystore2.AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.engineDoFinal(AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java:613)
> at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2055)
> at com.epicshaggy.biometric.NativeBiometric.encryptString(NativeBiometric.java:267)
> at com.epicshaggy.biometric.NativeBiometric.setCredentials(NativeBiometric.java:150)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.getcapacitor.PluginHandle.invoke(PluginHandle.java:121)
> at com.getcapacitor.Bridge.lambda$callPluginMethod$0$Bridge(Bridge.java:592)
> at com.getcapacitor.-$$Lambda$Bridge$25SFHybyAQk7zS27hTVXh2p8tmw.run(Unknown
> Source:8)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
> at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
> at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
> Caused by: android.security.KeyStoreException: Key user not authenticated
> at android.security.KeyStore2.getKeyStoreException(KeyStore2.java:356)
> at android.security.KeyStoreOperation.handleExceptions(KeyStoreOperation.java:78)
> at android.security.KeyStoreOperation.update(KeyStoreOperation.java:114)
> at android.security.keystore2.KeyStoreCryptoOperationChunkedStreamer$MainDataStream.update(KeyStoreCryptoOperationChunkedStreamer.java:222)
> at android.security.keystore2.KeyStoreCryptoOperationChunkedStreamer.update(KeyStoreCryptoOperationChunkedStreamer.java:156)
> at android.security.keystore2.KeyStoreCryptoOperationChunkedStreamer.doFinal(KeyStoreCryptoOperationChunkedStreamer.java:179)
> at android.security.keystore2.AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.engineDoFinal(AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java:603)

I tried answers from these threads with no luck:
[Error after Fingerprint touched on Samsung phones: android.security.KeyStoreException: Key user not authenticated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36043912/error-after-fingerprint-touched-on-samsung-phones-android-security-keystoreexce)
['Key user not authenticated', Understanding the Android KeyStore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50116276/key-user-not-authenticated-understanding-the-android-keystore)

I am testing with Pixel 6.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @TashPemhiwa yes, `setUserAuthenticationRequired` only works when the cipher object is returned from the response of authenticated prompt object.