# How to catch nested exceptions

Tags: java, kotlin, exception

I am getting the below exception. But the KeyStoreException is not caught. And I can read ProviderException. Can I first understand, why two exceptions are thrown and also, why I cannot catch KeyStoreException.

In my code -

```
try{
 generateKeyApi()
}catch(e: Exception){
 when(e){
 is KeyStoreException -> Log.i("Key store exception")
 else -> Log.i("Its not a keystore exception")
 }
}


05-26 12:33:20.104  3153  3153 E  : Exception occurred in the application's task.
05-26 12:33:20.104  3153  3153 E  : java.security.ProviderException: Keystore 
operation failed
05-26 12:33:20.104  3153  3153 E  : at 
 .engineGenerateKey(AndroidKeyStoreKeyGeneratorSpi.java:322)
05-26 12:33:20.104  3153  3153 E  : at javax.crypto.KeyGenerator.generateKey 
(KeyGenerator.java:604)
05-26 12:33:20.104  3153  3153 E  :     .....
05-26 12:33:20.104  3153  3153 E  : at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run 
  (FutureTask.java:266)
05-26 12:33:20.104  3153  3153 E  :     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback 
(Handler.java:789)
05-26 12:33:20.104  3153  3153 E  :     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage 
(Handler.java:98)
05-26 12:33:20.104  3153  3153 E  :     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
05-26 12:33:20.104  3153  3153 E  :     at android.os.HandlerThread.run 
(HandlerThread.java:65)
 05-26 12:33:20.104  3153  3153 E  : Caused by: android.security.KeyStoreException: 
 User authentication required
 05-26 12:33:20.104  3153  3153 E  :    at 
  android.security.KeyStore.getKeyStoreException(KeyStore.java:1112)
 05-26 12:33:20.104  3153  3153 E  :    at 
 android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreKeyGeneratorSpi 
.engineGenerateKey(AndroidKeyStoreKeyGeneratorSpi.java:323)
 05-26 12:33:20.104  3153  3153 E  :    ... 32 more
```

Comment: This doesn't look like java.

Comment: you'll have to check the code where the exception is thrown. if somewhere in that method call there is another try-catch, in which the stacktrace is printed, but the exception not re-thrown, you can't, unless you alter that code

Comment: The code from where it's thrown is not in my control. As its from Android OS.

Comment: @Aada if the code where the stacktrace is being logged or the exception is being handled, I don't think you can change that

Comment: take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50116276/key-user-not-authenticated-understanding-the-android-keystore

Answer (score 1):

Since you have tagged this question with `[java]` I am answering it from a Java perspective.

> Can I first understand, why two exceptions are thrown

What has happened is that the first exception has been caught and then wrapped in a second exception.  Something like this:

```
try {
    // do something that may throw KeyStoreException
} catch (android.security.KeyStoreException e) {
    // The e argument in the constructor makes the existing
    // KeyStoreException the "cause" for the new ProviderException
    throw new java.security.ProviderException("Keystore operation failed", e);  
}
```

This is all happening in Android library code.

---

> and also, why I cannot catch `KeyStoreException`.

Because it has been wrapped.  At the point in your code where you are attempting to catch the exception, the exception that is being propagated is `ProviderException`.  Only the exception that is being propagated can be caught.

In order to deal with the inner exception, you would need to do something like this:

```
 try {
     // do something that may throw ProviderException
 } catch (java.security.ProviderException e) {
     if (e.getCause() instanceof android.security.KeyStoreException) {
         Log.i("This is a keystore exception: ", e.getCause())
     } else {
         // You can reraise the wrapper exception if you want to ...
         throw e;
     }
 }
```

Java doesn't provide a way to *directly* catch a nested exception.  (And neither does Kotlin.)

Answer (score 0):

You can't catch that nested exception itself, but you can access it the way you do in your code using `getCause()`:

```
try{
 generateKeyApi()
}catch(e: ProviderException){ // that's the exception being thrown
 when(e.getCause()){ // that's what you're trying to access
 is KeyStoreException -> Log.i("Key store exception")
 else -> Log.i("Its not a keystore exception")
 }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just add multiple catch for your try method

```
try{
    generateKeyApi()
}
catch(e: KeyStoreException){
    Log.i("Key store exception")
}
catch (e: Exception) {
    Log.i("Its not a keystore exception")
}
```

Comment: And how would that help? You think KeyStoreException is not covered by Exception?

Comment: Clearly, the problem seems to come from the generateKeyApi() function, but it also says "why can't I catch the KeyStoreException".

Comment: java.security.ProviderException is the exception being thrown here

Comment: @Gireada no, the problem seems to come from: engineGenerateKey(). Most likely issue: the Exception is thrown and handled in that method.

Comment: but, either way, if the Exception were propagated to the generateKeyApi(), and it threw it, it would have been caught by: catch ( Exception ), since Exception is a parent to the one thrown

Comment: The main problem is the above stacktrace is thrown which is first 1. Catched by Exception. But on checking the type , it checks for as ProviderException. My goal is to check its nested exception - which is KeystoreExceptio under Provider Exception. That will help me to know why it failed. Kindly let me know.